# session_regenerate_id(): Session object destruction failed, when running site via security scanners?

Tags: php, security, session

Is this normal, as I have tried two different scanners and they both seem to produce the same errors, so I'm assuming maybe it has to do with the way scanners work - as I don't get these errors when viewing the site normally (the site also functions fine - as expected).

Ofcourse, I could just ignore it and clear the error log (when I've finished scanning my site), but I'm just curious and would like to know why (and if there is a 'fix')?

FYI:

- When the site is being scanned; I get the same error repeatedly (on pages where `session_regenerate_id(true)` is included).
- The scanners which I have tried are both free Firefox Add-ons; 'SQL Inject Me' (by Security Compass) and Websecurify.
- I'm running these tests on my site (via 'localhost').
- The sessions are file based.

Comment: have you contacted the add on authors?

Comment: @Dagon I don't think this is a bug on the add-on side, maybe more to do with the way the add-ons handle sessions perhaps, but I could be wrong, I'll drop an email to the authors though, but in the meantime it would be interesting to see what others think on here.

Comment: I got the error because I'm using sessionstorage in memcache, but did not have Memcached installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Ofcourse, I could just ignore it and clear the error log (when I've finished scanning my site), but I'm just curious and would like to know why (and if there is a 'fix')?

Upgrade your PHP version to the current stable one: PHP 5.4.7.

Run the security checks again. If the error still happens (which I highly doubt), this needs further inspection. In that case (and even earlier) you should have added your [session configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php) (it is larger than you might think) to the question.

Also the code which is triggering this is unknown. The function [`session_regenerate_id()`](http://php.net/session_regenerate_id) is normally used in the context of the session management.

Because the concept of session is not that easy to grasp many developers (incl. me) do errors in that field more often. Some useful debugging functions:

- [`session_status`](http://php.net/session_status)
- [`headers_list`](http://php.net/headers_list)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your code and the way you handle sessions.

You are running a scanner that is going through your website and trying to manipulate various inputs and than analyzing the responses to see if the attack succeeded.

When you have `session_regenerate_id(true)` on a page, that method call tries to delete the current session and start a new one.

The reason that this happens on the scanner is because the scanner is probably taking some paths through the applications that a typical user wouldn't take. So if the scanner hits a URL that executes PHP code that has `session_regenerate_id(true)` inside of it and there isn't a current session, than you will receive that error.

Ideally you should have a check before calling `session_regenerate_id(true)` to see if a current session exists. If it doesn't than you should take the user to the login page and ask them to re-authenticate.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score -2):

Try using `session_write_close();` before `session_regenerate_id(true)`.
A possible reason for the problem is that your code is creating parallel queries. I had the same trouble and this helped me.